# MS Exchange Server/EWS - When does it send calendar notifications?

Tags: java, notifications, push-notification, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm working on an application with Exchange using EWS Java. I would like to subscribe exchange server with push notification to get calendar events. I am just at the beginning of researching but could not find exact info about an issue.

I want to learn the presence status of the user according to his calendar data. As I understand from articles, when a user accepts a meeting, a notification will be sent to the application. Is there any other notification, when this meeting starts or ends? How can I know this user is busy/free at the current time? When does the exchange server send its push notifications exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question **How can I know this user is busy/free at the current time?**

GetUserAvailability Operation will help you 
reference link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa564001%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, in fact this method returns his time slot and it is possible to call this method periodically. But my aim is to get notified from EWS when his state is just changed. In the system, there will be lots of users, I want to be notified for their state changes. Otherwise, it will be costly to call this method for all users in a certain time period. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you used Subscribe and GetEvent Operation ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566188%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have used StreamSubscription to the Calendar folder. I get notifications when there is a creation, modification or deletion operation for an calendar item. But unfortunately, it does not send notification when an accepted meeting starts. It seems that notifications are item-based.

Comment: ohh so, in that case i can't help you sorry, i dnt know much about that.

Answer (score 0):

In exchange-2010, they have added a new EventType which you subscribe to : EventType.FreeBusyChanged